# How to check the request body with RSpec

Tags: rspec, net-http

I have the following method

```rb
def post_it(data_hash)
  uri = URI.parse("https://example.com/api")
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = true

  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
  request.content_type = "application/json"
  request.body = data_hash.to_json

  response = http.request(request)

  return {code: response.code, body: JSON.parse(response.body)}
end
```

And I'd like to test with RSpec two things:
1- The request is made to the expected uri.
2- The request is made with the expected body.

The first point has been covered with

```rb
 it "is posted to the expected endpoint" do
   expect(Net::HTTP::Post).to receive(:new).with("/api")
   Gateway.new.post_it({id: 123})
 end
```

But I can't find a way (without mocking everything, which I'd like not to do) to test the second point. I have tried with VCR but it seems to me I can verify only the response.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try [WebMock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock?tab=readme-ov-file#rspec) instead.

This gem supports mocking HTTP requests and asserting the request signature and response after the mock HTTP request was made using [request callback](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock?tab=readme-ov-file#request-callbacks).

Here's how we do it in your test:

```rb
describe Gateway
  let(:request_body) { { hello: 'world' } }
  
  before do
    # WebMock setup
    stub_request(:post, 'https://example.com/api')
      .to_return(body: { message: 'Success!' }.to_json)
  end

  context 'when client sends a request' do
    it 'has the correct request signature' do
      WebMock.after_request do |request| # with response: |req, resp|
        expect(request.uri.path).to eq('/api')
        expect(request.body).to eq(request_body.to_json)
      end

      described_class.new.post_it(request_body)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I stub different requests in the same spec? When I do the second is ignored, and I get errors.

Comment: @Sig Yes. You should be able to do so as long as you are correctly scoping your tests.